# minecraft forge 1.10 creating crafting recipes crashes minecraft

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am trying to make a mod but I encountered this issue. When I try to create a crafting recipe it crashes my game. I am really not sure why. I tried using
`Items.COOKED_BEEF` also tried `Item.cooked_beef`. I imported everything I needed but it still doesn't work.

```
package Nedas60.TestMod.init;

import net.minecraft.init.Items;
import net.minecraft.item.Item;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemStack;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.registry.GameRegistry;

public class ModCrafting {

    public static void register() {
        ItemStack diamond  = new ItemStack(Items.DIAMOND);
        ItemStack beef  = new ItemStack(Items.COOKED_BEEF);
        ItemStack DmdBeef = new ItemStack(ModItems.DiamondBeef);

        GameRegistry.addShapedRecipe(DmdBeef, diamond, beef);
    }
}
```

Eclipse says everything is okay here. Using lowercase letters `Items.cooked_beef` doesn't work. What is the problem?

Error log: http://pastebin.com/7nmk2tfr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to add a shaped recipe without defining a shape. You should either use a shapeless recipe, or set the recipe shape using 1-3 strings with 1-3 characters in each (1 string for each row, 1 character for each square in the row).

Some examples of shaped recipes:
`//diamond above beef
GameRegistry.addShapedRecipe(DmdBeef, "D", "B", 'D', diamond, 'B', beef);`

`//diamond on the left of beef
GameRegistry.addShapedRecipe(DmdBeef, "DB", 'D', diamond, 'B', beef);`

`//diamond on the left of beef, with a blank space to the left, and 2 blank rows beneath it
GameRegistry.addShapedRecipe(DmdBeef, "ADB", "AAA", "AAA", 'D', diamond, 'B', beef);`

There are plenty more tutorials and examples on the forge documentation site, the minecraftforums and just googling will show some more.

The characters you use are not important, you could use '@' for diamond for example. Any characters not specified (such as 'A' in the last example) will be required to be blank. If not all 9 characters are specified, the ones that are can be put in the correct formation anywhere in the grid.

Just as an aside, standard java practice is to have variables start with a lowercase letter (`DmdBeef` should be `dmdBeef`).

Comment: Didnt notice that:D I actually intended to do not shaped. Thanks A LOT!